# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() doesn't save cropped image

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to save a cropped image to the camera roll.
(I need to do it programmatically, I can't have the user edit it)

This is my (still quite basic) cut and save code:

```
- (void)cutAndSaveImage:(UIImage*)rawImage
{
    CIImage *workingImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:rawImage];

    CGRect croppingRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 3264.0f, 1224.0f);
    CIImage *croppedImage = [workingImage imageByCroppingToRect:croppingRect];

    UIImage *endImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:croppedImage scale: 1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];

    self.testImage.image = endImage;

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(rawImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:) , nil);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(endImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:) , nil);
}
```

The method is called within:
`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info`

- I first create a `CIImage` using the raw `UIImage`.
- Then I get a cropped `CIImage` using an instance method of the first one.
- After that I create a new `UIImage` using the cropped CIImage.

At this point, to have some feedback, I set the new cropped `UIImage` as the backing image of a `UIImageView`. This works, and I can clearly see the image cropped exactly how I desired.

When I try to save it to the camera roll, however, things stop working.
I can't save the newly created `endImage`.
As you can see, I added a line to save the original `UIImage` too, just for comparison. The original one saves normally.

Another confusing thing is that the `NSError` object passed to the `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` callback is nil. (the callback is normally executed for both saving attempts)

EDIT:
Just made an experiment:

```
NSLog(@"rawImage: %@    -   rawImage.CGImage: %@", rawImage, rawImage.CGImage);
NSLog(@"endImage: %@    -   endImage.CGImage: %@", endImage, endImage.CGImage);
```

It looks like only the `rawImage` (coming from the `UIImagePickerController`) possesses a backing `CGImageRef`. The other one, created from a `CIImage`, doesn't.

Can it be that `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` works using the backing `CGImageRef`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can it be that UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum works using the backing CGImageRef?

Correct. A CIImage is not an image, and a UIImage backed only by a CIImage is not an image either; it is just a kind of wrapper. Why are you using CIImage at all here? You aren't using CIFilter so this makes no sense. Or if you *are* using CIFilter, you must render through a CIContext to get the output as a bitmap.

You can crop easily by drawing into a smaller graphics context.

Comment: Thanks. Actually this is just a preliminary test. I'll be needing CIFilters later. I know there is a filter to crop CIImages, and maybe I'll use that directly. Anyway, could you please provide a plain example of cropping by drawing into a smaller graphics context? Also, how would I use a CIContext to turn the CIImage back into a bitmap? Cheers.

Comment: Cropping by drawing into a smaller context: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_uiimage_drawing

Comment: What CIImage is for: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_cifilter_and_ciimage

Answer (score 2):

If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object, the
value of the property is NULL.

You can generate UIImage from CIImage like this:

```
let lecturePicture = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!)!)!
let controlsFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
controlsFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: lecturePicture), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
controlsFilter.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
let displayImage = UIImage(CGImage: CIContext(options:nil).createCGImage(controlsFilter.outputImage, fromRect:controlsFilter.outputImage.extent()))!
displayImage
```